# extra black border line

Tags: html, css, media-queries

when you reduce the browser window u will see a different layout for iphone
I see an extra black line below the slider...
how to remove the black line....
i removed the border property but its not getting removed....
providing my code below....

http://jsfiddle.net/CAARt/1/

```
#slider li div {
border-radius: 4px;
border-top: 1px #fff solid;
background: #F7F9FA;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px #0D0F11;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px #0D0F11;
box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px #0D0F11;
color: #DDE1E4;
font-size: 12px;
text-align: center;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
color: #A4AEB7;
}
```

Comment: Don't use tags that don't apply to your question

Comment: @JohnConde: updated my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/CAARt/1/embedded/result/

Answer (score 0):

When the window size is reduced, the border that you are seeing is caused by this

```
#gallery nav {
border-top:1px solid #3A4146;
}
```

Change that border to 0px or none and it will go away.